# can we do AOP logging for class which is not annotated with spring annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, java.util.logging, spring-logback

I want to do AspectJ logging for this class, can anyone suggest to me how to do it or will it even be possible?

```java
public class Class{
  public void method(){
    // code
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it Spring-managed Bean?

Comment: No Dias, Its regular java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Spring AOP will only handle Spring-managed Beans.